# _unAnswered_ Turn on android hotspot by button click in my application then see the connected devices MAC address

Tags: android

I want to turn on the hotspot of my android mobile as i click on button in my hello world application.
After that I also want below that the list of all connected devices MAC address must be seen.
And there will be option of giving the custom name to those MAC address(alias).

This question is asked way before stack overflow and never answered properly. So please try to give **ANS**

Answer (score 0):

We will not give you the code to do this. But this is a way you can explore.

To control the wifi of your android device you have to add this line to your manifest :

```
<manifest ...>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
...
</manifest>
```

After you have to use the class : WifiManager to manage the hotspot

Comment: I know about permission I wanted a bit of code. Just answer about how to turn on hostspot?

Comment: wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(true)  with wifimanager a Wifimanager object

Comment: can you talk to me in general about this project on other platform like mail